# What's the difference between following two queries?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, pymysql

What is the difference between first and second query?

[image]

First Query- Handwritten

```
select brandId from brand where brandName="Brand - A";
```

Second Query- query sent to be executed from python via 'pymysql'

```
select brandId from brand where brandName="Brand - A";
```

Exact python query which gave the error and led me to try the above:

```
Select brandId from brand where brandName like "%Brand – A%" and networkId=5803423295340544;
```

I don't understand why the second query is giving me an 'empty set'. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok  I have added the queries. But I got the data from excel sheet and then sent the data to an API and storing the response from API and storing the result in mySQL. Now I am accessing the response from python with same data from  same excel sheet.

Comment: Can you post the exact python function, as in from the source code?

Comment: Are you sure the minus characters are the same? see for example: https://www.punctuationmatters.com/the-difference-between-a-dash-and-a-minus-sign/